# Subjunctive Mood in Second Conditional - Inversion

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conditionals, subject-verb-inversion

The sentence

> If I were you, I wouldn't do this

One can add emphasis to the sentence, by saying

> Were I you, I wouldn't do this

However, I noticed that in everyday English people tend not to use the subjunctive mood, but standard Simple Past tense.

> If I was you, I wouldn't do this.

So, is it possible to say

> Was I you, I wouldn't do this?

It looks a little bit strange for me.

Comment: "If I were you"/"Were I you" (NOTE: Not "was") is correct. However, English speakers don't necessarily speak correctly. Subjunctive is a hard mood and you will hear the incorrect "was" a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If I was you, I wouldn't do this.*

While many nuances of the subjunctive mood has now been abandoned, such as "If that's the house you were hoping to buy ...", I would suggest that ***If I was you ...*** is still irregular, and sounds odd, and many people would still use "were".

But whatever the state of subjunctive "were", if you do wish to invert it, then ***Were I you*** is the correct usage, if somewhat stilted.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, I don't think this answer deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your analysis: **"Was I you, I wouldn't do this"** is incorrect usage. One could certainly say it, but not without sounding very strange indeed, just as you noted.

Comment: Exactly so. Exactly so.

Answer (score 1):

No native English speaker would say

- **Were I you, I wouldn't do this.*
  nor would they say
- **Was I you, I wouldn't do this.*

That's because ***If I were you*** is a fixed phrase and doesn't vary.

- *If I were you, I wouldn't do this.*
  but not
- **If I was you, I wouldn't do this.*

Comment: In British English, the results from corpus studies, surprisingly, didn't back that up as much as one would think they would have. "If I was you" is reasonably common in spoken English, it seems - at least in the UK. If you dig through [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22if+i+was+you%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=lKNoVoP7HIntaKuCocAJ) enough , you'll find enough good examples from books. I've got no idea what the situation is in American English though. (I'm pretty certain that the inversions are extremely rare, if not non-existent though)